# How can I list the key groups for GPG?

Tags: gnupg

Say I've setup or defined a key group or a number of key groups. How do I list those groups? How can I determine what keys are members of those groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gpg --with-colons --list-config group
```

From [Using the GNU Privacy Guard: GPG Esoteric Options](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html#GPG-Esoteric-Options):

> `--list-config`
>
> Display various internal configuration parameters of GnuPG. This option is intended for external programs that call GnuPG to perform tasks, and is thus not generally useful. See the file `doc/DETAILS` in the source distribution for the details of which configuration items may be listed. `--list-config` is only usable with `--with-colons` set.

From the `doc/DETAILS` file in [the source of GPG 1.4.22](https://www.gnupg.org/download/index.html):

```
Format of the "--list-config" output
====================================

--list-config outputs information about the GnuPG configuration for
the benefit of frontends or other programs that call GnuPG.  There are
several list-config items, all colon delimited like the rest of the
--with-colons output.  The first field is always "cfg" to indicate
configuration information.  The second field is one of (with
examples):

...

group: the third field contains the name of the group, and the fourth
       field contains the values that the group expands to, separated
       by semicolons.

For example, a group of:
   group mynames = paige 0x12345678 joe patti

would result in:
   cfg:group:mynames:patti;joe;0x12345678;paige
```